# Cannot use JS library in React Native application

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm using these JS libraries in my project

- Hybrid Crypto JS ([link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hybrid-crypto-js))
- Bcrypt ([link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-bcrypt))

When I use these libraries to crypt data, it can execute the crypting funtion and return the cipher String. But afther that, it always throws this error

> Error: Requiring unknown module "undefined". If you are sure the module exists, try restarting Metro. You may also want to run `yarn` or `npm install`.
> at node_modules\expo\build\logs\LogSerialization.js:155:14 in _captureConsoleStackTrace
> at node_modules\expo\build\logs\LogSerialization.js:41:26 in serializeLogDataAsync

Here is my code

```
import { Crypt, RSA } from 'hybrid-crypto-js';
import bcrypt from 'bcryptjs';

const publicKey  = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY----------ENDPUBLICKEY----";
const encrypt = (userInfo) => {
const {...} = userInfo;

const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
const hash = bcrypt.hashSync(data, salt);

const str = "mydata"

const crypt = new Crypt({rsaStandard: 'RSAES-PKCS1-V1_5', aesIvSize: 16});
const encrypted = crypt.encrypt(publicKey, str);

const encryptedObj = JSON.parse(encrypted);
return Object.values(encryptedObj.keys)[0] + ',' + encryptedObj.iv + ',' + encryptedObj.cipher;
}

const Crypting = {
  encrypt,
}

export default Crypting;
```

And this is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "mobile-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
 },
 "dependencies": {
 "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.15.17",
 "axios": "^0.25.0",
 "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
 "expo": "~44.0.0",
 "expo-app-loading": "^1.3.0",
 "expo-asset": "^8.4.6",
 "expo-constants": "^13.0.2",
 "expo-font": "^10.0.5",
 "expo-status-bar": "~1.2.0",
 "hybrid-crypto-js": "^0.2.4",
 "react": "17.0.2",
 "react-dom": "17.0.2",
 "react-native": "0.64.3",
 "react-native-elements": "^3.4.2",
 "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.3.2",
 "react-native-screens": "^3.10.2",
 "react-native-web": "0.17.1"
 },
"devDependencies": {
  "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
  "dotenv": "^16.0.0",
  "jest": "^27.5.1"
 },
"private": true
}
```

Also, there is always some strange messages on my import line.

> Could not find a declaration file for module 'hybrid-crypto-js'. 'myproject/node_modules/hybrid-crypto-js/lib/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
> Try `npm i --save-dev @types/hybrid-crypto-js` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'hybrid-crypto-js';

This error appears everytime I call my function that use the libraries. I'm using React native with Expo. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: What does your code look like? Did you install the libraries?

Comment: May you show your package.json/

Comment: Please share your package.json file.

Comment: I just updated my code and package.json file

Comment: I am facing similar issue. Can anyone please help?

Comment: @khurshed_nosirov what library are you using? Can you post that library? If you are working on Expo, It cannot use library with native codes like Java or Swift. Expo only works with library built on Javascript or Typescript... so be careful with the library you are using

Comment: @Mink I am using the bcryptjs library. Is should be compatible with Expo, no?

Comment: @khurshed_nosirov Yes, it is compatible with Expo, but the function which generated salt (genSaltSync) is somehow broken. My solution is you can implement that function yourself. Just a function random generates  alphanumeric character

Comment: @Mink But then I can't use the hash function. It will be throwing an "Error: Invalid salt version: ... "  error.

Comment: @khurshed_nosirov yes you can, i think you have not implemented it correctly. I'll post my code in the reply for reference

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is genSalt in Bcrypt is broken...

```
const ALPHANUMERIC = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

const randomSalt = (length) => {
    let randomStr = '';
    for(let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        randomStr += ALPHANUMERIC.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * ALPHANUMERIC.length));
    }
    return randomStr;
};

const salt = "$2a$10$" + randomSalt(22);
const hash = bcrypt.hashSync(myString, salt);
```

The code above is my solution to implement gen salt function my self. I've noticed that the (genSaltSync) in the library always starts with '$2a$10$' when pass length = 10 to its parameter, so it's the prefix. After that, it always generates 22 random characters when length = 10, so I'll create 22 random characters by my new function... and it just works.